# Loading xml with encoding UTF 16 using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2008, unicode

I am trying to read the xml document using XDocument method .
but i am getting an error when xml has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

When i removed encoding manually.It works perfectly.

I am getting error " **There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.** "

i tried searching and i landed up here-->

[Why does C# XmlDocument.LoadXml(string) fail when an XML header is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310669/why-does-c-xmldocument-loadxmlstring-fail-when-an-xml-header-is-included)

But could not  solve my problem.

My code :

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

Any suggestions ??

thank you.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks like the file you are trying to read is not encoded as Unicode.  You can replicate the behavior by trying to open a file encoded as ANSI with the encoding in the XML file specified as `utf-16`.

If you can't ensure that the file is encoded properly, then you can read the file into a stream (letting the `StreamReader` detect the encoding) and then create the `XDocument`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, true))
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
```

Comment: I have my the output of XML being spit into html. The above solution did not work for me. I have a copyright symbol (c) in my text of the xml document and it always gets garbled when the HTML comes to the browser. So I tried to encode (XML encode the HTML encoded string) but it literally comes out as it is in HTML. i.e. &amp;copy; in xml literally comes out as &amp;copy; instead of the expected &copy; so that the browser can display the (c).

Answer (score 10):

I tried , and found another way of doing it !!

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path));
```

Comment: Wow!  This is new, 4.5 was just released!  (2012-08-15 - 5 days ago)  :)  Way to stay up on your framework Sangram!

Comment: From what I can tell the XDocument.Parse() method was new and just introduced to .Net 4.5 framework.  That was released on 2012-08-15 which at the time was 5 days ago...  It was simply a complement, usually people just say thanks for a complement. :P

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that :) but i think existed from 3.5 because i am still using 3.5 :P check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Well then I stand corrected!  :)  When you search for "XDocument.Parse()" on Google it shows you the 4.5 framework pages only...  :/  And the reason I was so quick to accept that was because I use 4.0 and for some reason it was not showing up natively...  Now that I go back and try it again, it seems to be working fine...  So I guess I retract my original comment. :P  Not sure what I was smoking that day...  Sorry ;)

Comment: LOL !! no need to be sorry. at least we both learned something new. :)

Comment: This doesn't compile for me as the Parse method accepts a string and the ReadAllLines method returns a string array! Shouldn't it be ReadAllText?

Comment: XDocument.Parse expects a string, so File.ReadAllLines doesn't compile.  You have to use File.ReadAllText.  At least, that's how it's working for me in VS2017.

Answer (score 7):

This code:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

returns an array of strings.
The correct code is:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
```

Comment: okay. that's another way to do it. but readAllLines does work.

Comment: Best way to do it, no complications. Thank you.