# XElement fails to load file with accented characters

Tags: .net, xelement

I have a rather curious problem, using the XElement load method to load in a html document (which is well formed checked with HTML Tidy), which work absolutely perfectly for English documents, however moving to French and Spanish docs I'm presented with an XML Exception;

```
XML Exception
Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 23, position 43.
```

The method call

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("example1.html", LoadOptions.None);
```

Sniplet of the html document

```
<font face="Arial" size="3" color="#ffffff">
Le test <b> exemple français, qui devrait éventuellement être suivie d'un texte en langue espagnole. </ b>
</font>
```

I realise my HTML does not have an encoding type set at the start of the file, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you're not using XDocument you can't set character encoding, use that instead and set encoding = UTF-8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, eventually after a digging around I found this as well; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310669/why-does-c-xmldocument-loadxmlstring-fail-when-an-xml-header-is-included