# Xml text cannot contain the "One Half" &frac12; html character?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-parsing

So I'm reading in some xml from a 3rd party (read: I cannot determine or touch the xml coming to me) and one of the files had the following ...

`.. within 2 &frac12; hours to major centers ...`

When I remove the offending word `[&frac12;]` it loads into the Dom.

```
// First, read in the XML.
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlText);
```

I know the proper solution here would be to `CData` that text stuff - but I can't get 'em to change their data. (Personally, the real solution would be to goto `json` but lets not go there...)

I really don't want to have to have a blacklist of *words* which i strip out :( That sounds .. painful. Especially when the text can be sorta large .. like upto 1MB. Just feels *wrong*.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Urgh.

Found my own answer :( Xml only allows **5 predefined entities** out of the box.

Everything else has to be declared manually in a DTD.

To [quote wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

> The XML specification does not use the term "character entity" or
>   "character entity reference". The XML specification defines five
>   "predefined entities" representing special characters, and requires
>   that all XML processors honor them. The entities can be explicitly
>   declared in a DTD, as well, but if this is done, the replacement text
>   must be the same as the built-in definitions. XML also allows other
>   named entities of any size to be defined on a per-document basis.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130865/loading-xml-document-fails-with-special-character-raquo) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595041/xelement-fails-to-load-file-with-accented-characters) talk about this.