# asp.net  XML: reading xml node and displaying encoded text

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

A web service returns an xml string with french text in it. When printing the xml node

```
 xmlResponse.LoadXml(resp);
 XmlNode Text = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("/res/Text");
 sMessageText = Text.InnerText;
```

the text looks like this:

> e.g. Le nom de le propri�taire de carte doit �tre entre 4 et 32
>   caract�res

How do I encode it? How do I show readable text.

Thank you

Comment: You can use the [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to convert the text, but are you creating this XML or consuming from somewhere else? because you shouldn't need to do any conversion, if your xml have the correct encoding.

Comment: the xml response is coming from another system. I was just thinking maybe I have to capture the xml response some other way...
currently I am using LoadXml.


   string resp = Calling webservice....
   xmlResponse.LoadXml(resp);

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set the cultureinfo of the control that is to use the string, i'm not sure of which property but you should assign it to `CultureInfo("fr-FR");`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a method out of the box in XmlDocument class to load and convert the encoding. You can try the following, its from the link i gave you, the documentation for [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
  Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
  Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

  // Convert the string into a byte array.
  byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

  // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
  byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

  // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
  char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
  ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
  string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);
```

You just need to change it for the encodings you're using. Also you might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310669/why-does-c-sharp-xmldocument-loadxmlstring-fail-when-an-xml-header-is-included), it has many answers that might help you.