# Add and remove columns from a Tablix in rdlc report

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I want to create a report with dynamic number of columns.
I have used the solutions of these two following links to load and modify my rdlc report file.

1. http://dobrzanski.net/2009/02/06/how-to-dynamically-add-new-columns-to-report-created-with-reporting-services/
2. [Why does C# XmlDocument.LoadXml(string) fail when an XML header is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310669/why-does-c-sharp-xmldocument-loadxmlstring-fail-when-an-xml-header-is-included)

but the problem is that when i use the Save method of xmlDocument to save the report anything happens.

what is my mistake???

Comment: Also look this post: [c-sharp-2015-winform-datagrid-view-selected-rows-to-rdlc-report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589990/c-sharp-2015-winform-datagrid-view-selected-rows-to-rdlc-report/48034544#48034544)