# Does the Deployment Device I choose for a Windows CE project affect the EXEs behavior?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, emulation, device, setup-deployment

In trying to track down any possible reason for failures with my .EXE/.DLL Windows CE / Compact Framework pair (delineated here [[What is wrong with this HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse code (why is it considered a "bad" request (400))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652692/what-is-wrong-with-this-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse-code-why-is-it-considere])), I found this setting selected for Deployment Device

[image]

(Windows CE .NET Emulator (Default) is what is selected)

Would it be better / make any difference if I chose "Windows CE .NET Device" instead?

This seems to make more sense, as I don't use an emulator - I copy the .exe I build in XP Mode / Visual Studio 2003 to the handheld device and run it directly from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference.  The compiled assemblies are the same.  The deployment device only affects which device Visual Studio will attempt to push the output binaries to during the Deploy phase.  And really these are just names that don't matter much.  It's purely from the list of configured devices.  You can make the "Emulator" target push to a physical device over CoreCon.  You can make the "Pocket PC" device push to a general Windows CE device.  These are just canned, helpful targets with specific settings.