# Getting "Invalid character in the given encoding."

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, svg

I am exporting image via svg. Below is my `c#` code.

```
string chartTitle = "ABC 50 µG";
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.XmlResolver = null;

string chartSvg = "<svg><text x=\"1\" y=\"15\" font-size=\"14\" font-weight='bold' font-family=\"Arial\" ><tspan x=\"458\" dy=\"10\"> " + chartTitle + "</tspan></text></svg>"

xd.LoadXml(chartSvg);
svgGraph = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(xd);
```

I am getting error `Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 110.` at last line above due to `µ` symbol in my `chartTitle`.

Please help, how can i tackle this

Comment: You tried replacing `µ` with `\u00B5`

Comment: @AlvinK. tried this, but in exported image its showing `ABC 50 \u00B5G`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310669/why-does-c-sharp-xmldocument-loadxmlstring-fail-when-an-xml-header-is-included - need the UTF8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution with below code.

```
string chartTitle = "ABC 50 µG";
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.XmlResolver = null;

string chartSvg = "<svg><text x=\"1\" y=\"15\" font-size=\"14\" font-weight='bold' font-family=\"Arial\" ><tspan x=\"458\" dy=\"10\"> " + chartTitle + "</tspan></text></svg>"

xd.LoadXml(chartSvg);    
XmlDeclaration obj = xd.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", "yes");
XmlElement root = xd.DocumentElement;
xd.InsertBefore(obj, root);
svgGraph = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(xd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var byteArr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(svgContents);
using (var str = new MemoryStream(byteArr))
{
   var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(str);
   var bitmap = svgDoc.Draw();
   bitmap.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Also look at the [SVG Engine codeplex](http://svg.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Tried this..getting "Specified document not found" exception