# read xml file on c#, reading the arabic text provide a encrypted string not actual utf-8

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, localization, lang

xml file-> for example this is hosted on the url **http://localhost/test1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<MSG>
    <arabic>
        <translationOne>اول</translationOne>
        <translationTwo>دوم</translationTwo>
    </arabic> 
     <persian>
          <translationOne>یک</translationOne>
          <translationTwo>دوم</translationTwo>
    </persian> 
</MSG>
```

c# class

```
            var m_strFilePath = "http://localhost/test1";
            string xmlStr;
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
            }
            var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
            XmlNodeList unNodeA = xmldoc.SelectNodes("MSG/arabic");
            XmlNodeList unNodeP = xmldoc.SelectNodes("MSG/persian");
            string arabic = "";
            foreach (XmlNode i in unNodeA)
            {
                 arabic += i["translationOne"].InnerText;
            }
            string persian= "";
            string persian2 ="";
            foreach (XmlNode ii in unNodeP)
            {
                 persian+= ii["translationOne"].InnerText;
                 persian2+= ii["translationTwo"].InnerText;
            }
             
            ->>print(arabic and persian);
```

here the test contain not correct format like (اول دوم) it's some kind of (Ø¹Ø¨Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø²ÙŠØ² Ø¹Ø¨Ø§Ø³ÛŒÙ†)

Comment: Is your console UTF-8? Did you check if the strings actually are correct and the output is just wrong? (Also System.out.print is Java, not C#, so not sure how this code would work)

Comment: yes i am just printing this sorry i mixed these too it's getting print but the encoding is not correct, i search they told to parse but i am fetching this from url

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310669/why-does-c-sharp-xmldocument-loadxmlstring-fail-when-an-xml-header-is-included

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use **LINQ to XML** API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><MSG>
            <arabic>
                <translationOne>اول</translationOne>
                <translationTwo>دوم</translationTwo>
            </arabic> 
             <persian>
                  <translationOne>یک</translationOne>
                  <translationTwo>دوم</translationTwo>
            </persian> 
        </MSG>");

    foreach (XElement elem in xdoc.Descendants("arabic").Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("translation: {0}", elem.Value);
    }
}
```

If you need to load XML from the URL:

```
const string Url = @"http://hurt.super-toys.pl/xml/super_toys_ceneo_pelny.xml";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Url);
```

**Output**

```
translation: اول
translation: دوم
```

Comment: i am getting this from url out source

Comment: @SAR, I updated the answer to show how to load XML file from the URL.

Comment: i have several nodes so i want to specify node in foreach  XmlNodeList unNode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("MSG/arabic");

Comment: @SAR, (1) Please update your original question with the real XML. (2) There is no need to use ancient XML API. **LINQ to XML** is available already for 14 years. It made earlier XML APIs quasi deprecated.

Comment: @SAR, because `<translation>` element stays the same, the same code in the answer will work without any change.

Comment: there are tow nodes (arabic and persian) how i can only show arabic. in my case it's fine showing the result but arabic encode not work

Comment: @SAR, check it out now.

Comment: on the question one change i made if you have time to check

Comment: @SAR, you modified XML element names and made XML **NOT well-formed**. You need to fix your XML first and make it well-formed. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: changes were made

Comment: @SAR, overall, it is a poor design decision to name XML elements as translationOne, translationTwo, translationThree, etc. If you really need a numeric id, it is better to use an attribute: `<translation id="1">`, `<translation id="2">`

Comment: The current answer will process whatever XML element names are. No need for any changes.